# Disable elementary from DBT CLI when running dbt test

Tags: dbt

I have [Elementary](https://docs.elementary-data.com/understand-elementary/elementary-overview) installed in my DBT project:

```yaml
# packages.yml
packages:
  - package: elementary-data/elementary
    version: 0.9.0

# dbt_project.yml
models:
  elementary:
    +schema: elementary
```

When I run DBT from the CLI, elementary will open connections and model executions, as well as test executions + results. ***I'd like to disable elementary's behavior, from the CLI.*** *(Not sure if it's possible...)*

An ideal solution would be a CLI flag:

```bash
dbt run -s my_model --disable-elementary
```

*(I do not want to alter my profiles... or dbt_project.yml)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an environment variable for this that is read in from `dbt_project.yml` (I know you said you don't want to alter `dbt_project.yml`, but this is dynamic):

```
models:
  elementary:
    +schema: "elementary"
    +enabled: "{{ env_var('DBT_ELEMENTARY_ENABLED') | as_bool }}"
```

Comment: Solves my problem, albeit less elegant than I'd like. Hopefully this isn't the only way, but it looks like it is...

Comment: @YaakovBressler I'm curious why you think this is not an elegant solution. I'm pretty sure this is the approach the DBT devs would recommend.